# compare two arrays and remove - PHP ARRAY

Tags: php, arrays

Please see the following arrays, I want to hide 6 and 7 in array while loop since those were in first array, basicaly its timing. Frst array contains appointments, second array contains timings.  I want to omit timing (second array) if the user already fixed somewhere at that time. So basically time comparision with strtotime integer..Need your help....

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 100
            [start] => 1364558400
            [end] => 1364565600
            [starttime] => 2013-03-29 17:30:00
            [endtime] => 2013-03-29 19:30:00
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 100
            [start] => 1364542200
            [end] => 1364549400
            [starttime] => 2013-03-29 13:00:00
            [endtime] => 2013-03-29 15:00:00
        )

)
Array
(
    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 37
            [start] => 1364542200
            [end] => 1364549400
            [starttime] => 2013-03-29 13:00:00
            [endtime] => 2013-03-29 15:00:00
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 38
            [start] => 1364549400
            [end] => 1364556600
            [starttime] => 2013-03-29 15:00:00
            [endtime] => 2013-03-29 17:00:00
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 39
            [start] => 1364558400
            [end] => 1364565600
            [starttime] => 2013-03-29 17:30:00
            [endtime] => 2013-03-29 19:30:00
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => 40
            [start] => 1364565600
            [end] => 1364571000
            [starttime] => 2013-03-29 19:30:00
            [endtime] => 2013-03-29 21:00:00
        )

)
```

Comment: your question somehow is not clear

Comment: user 100 appointed at [starttime] => 2013-03-29 17:30:00            [endtime] => 2013-03-29 19:30:00 and [starttime] => 2013-03-29 13:00:00 [endtime] => 2013-03-29 15:00:00...thats what array 1 shows...I got 2nd array to show predefined timings and want to compare 1st array and omit 6,7 since the user already appointed at that time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood your problem, you should unset elements of the second array. Let's assume your arrays are:

```
$appointments = array(...);
$timings = array(...);
```

You should do

```
if (condition_is_met($appointments)) {
    unset($timings[$id]);
}
```

Is that what you need?

edit:
I guess you're looking for something like this:

```
foreach($timings as $timing) { // check if this timing is already busy
  $id = null;
  foreach ($appointments as $id => $appointment) {
    if ($appointment['start'] == $timing['start'] &&
      $appointment['end'] == $timing['end'] ) {
      $found = $id;
      break;
    }
  }
  if ($id) unset($appointments[$id]);
}
```

It depends on what is the condition dealing with times - should both start and end be the same in both elements or just have at least one seconds from the same period. You can change the if statement and put there whatever you want.

Comment: I think this will do the trick...but small correction is it possible to check in between timing instead of exact timing?

Comment: yes, it is possible. Just change == to <= and >= and this will be it.

Comment: perfect buddy...but I am still working in <= and >= part...hope will finished as soon as possibel..learning day...thanks dear friend...

Comment: you're welcome ;). Next time try to provide more detailed question. People won't ask you additional questions and you'll get good answers straight away.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you're trying to remove elements in the second array if they appear in the first array.  Please see:

```
foreach($array2 as $i)
{
  if (in_array($i, $array1))
  {
    unset($i);
  }
}
```

Ref.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Or, you could create a function like:

```
function checkItemExists($arr1, $arr2)
{
  $index1 = 0;
  $index2 = 0;
  foreach ($arr1 as $i)
  {
    foreach ($i as $j)
    {
      if ($j == $arr2[$index1][$index2])
      {
        unset($arr2[$index1][$index2]);
      }
     index2++;
    }
   $index1++;
   $index2 = 0;
  }
}
```